# MySQL WHERE Clause between two values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm attempting to select all the rows based on whether or not it falls within the limits of two numbers.  For example, I want all the rows who's limits include the number 4.  So if a row that had a start value of 2 and end value of 7 would be returned.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM egw_scripture_reference
WHERE book = 'Revelation'
  AND end_verse <= 4 
  AND start_verse >= 4
```

Comment: What is your issue? Waht is not working?

Comment: Then your condition should be `AND end_verse >= 4 AND start_verse <= 4`.

Answer (score 1):

If `a row that had a start value of 2 and end value of 7 should be returned` then your filter condition should be as shown here.

```
SELECT * FROM egw_scripture_reference 
WHERE book = 'Revelation' AND end_verse >= 4 AND start_verse <= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong, as you said: **if a row that had a start value of 2 and end value of 7 would be returned** you will need this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM egw_scripture_reference 
WHERE book = 'Revelation' 
AND end_verse >= 4 
AND start_verse <= 4
```